# Minimal input width growing with value

Tags: css, reactjs, input, layout, flexbox

I have a form in react app which has

- labels on the left side
- inputs for values + units on the right side

All elements uses display:flex by default.

I need the input size to have a **minimum width 30px**, but in case the **input number is longer** (i.e. 8 digits), I need the input to **stretch** itself up to his maximum width 80px, while still being aligned on the right.

Here is a fiddle of the form 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrweLQ

HTML of row:

```
<div class="formRow formRowEven">
    <div class="label">Long value</div>
    <div class="valueWrapper">
      <div class="value">
        <input value="12345678"/>
      </div>
      <div class="unit">min</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.formRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.label {
  flex: 1 1;
}
.valueWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.value {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

input {
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 30px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;  
}
```

And here is an image of the ideal state.

[image]

I can't figure out setting of the left side for the inputs / units, anyone help?

Comment: Although most HTML elements scale to for their content, there are a few exceptions, including most of the form components (text areas, input fields, and selects being among the most prevalent.  You'll have to use a dom `onInput` event handler to grow the input dynamically when text is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanFarrell said, `<input />` in html is not designed for inline display.

Use `<span />` with `contentEditable="true"`, with modified codepen https://codepen.io/valuis/pen/LeVrbx

and code snippet:

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300);
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

html {
  font-size: 17px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #111;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #48435C;
  margin: 2rem auto 0;
  max-width: 80%;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.formRow {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.formRowOdd {
  background: #383850;  
}

/* LAYOUT */
.formRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
}
.valueWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.value {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 80px;
  flex: 1 0 30px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <div class="formRow formRowOdd">
    <div class="label">Short value</div>
    <div class="valueWrapper">
      <div class="value">
        <span contentEditable="true">123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="unit">min</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formRow formRowEven">
    <div class="label">Long value</div>
    <div class="valueWrapper">
      <div class="value">
        <span contentEditable="true">1234567</span>
      </div>
      <div class="unit">min</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formRow formRowOdd">
    <div class="label">Value to be filled</div>
    <div class="valueWrapper">
      <div class="value">
        <span contentEditable="true" />
      </div>
      <div class="unit">min</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the size and onInput properties of the input :

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('');

<input
    size={value.length > 3 ? value.length : 3}
    onInput={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
    type="text"
    value={value}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div with content editable instead of an input, so you can expand it as you type.
Then you just push the text into the hidden input.

Something like this:

```js
   var fakeInput = document.getElementById('yourFakeInput');
   var Inputelement = document.getElementById('theRealInput');
        
        fakeInput.onblur = function() {
          Inputelement.value = fakeInput.innerHTML;
          console.log(fakeInput.clientWidth + 'px');
}
```

```css
 div {
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div id='yourFakeInput' contenteditable="true">type here...</div>
    <input id='theRealInput' type='hidden'>
```